# Handshake problem? Determining potential passing lines in a rondo (football / soccer)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm hoping someone can help me with what I *think* is a rather complicated handshake problem...

I'm trying to determine the degree of complexity between 3 different rondo drills in football / soccer, by calculating the number of potential passing lines in each.

The 3 rondos are

- **Rondo A:** 4 players passing around the perimeter of a circle
- **Rondo B:** 5 players passing around the perimeter of a circle
- **Rondo C:** 4 players passing around the perimeter of a circle with a 5th player inside as an optional connector of passes (i.e. they can pass directly to each other or connect passes through the 5th player)

Now, since the players can move laterally to relatively discrete positions during play, the dynamic changes. Since lateral positions between players could potentially be numerous, maybe it's best to simplify this number to specific key positions.

- **Rondo A:** The 4 perimeter players can occupy 3 positions each (along their respective sides)
- **Rondo B:** The 5 perimeter players can occupy 3 positions each
- **Rondo C:** The 4 perimeter players can occupy 3 positions each, but the central player can occupy 5 discrete positions

I made a somewhat [simple diagram to illustrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVZix.png) how this might play out.

Now, I *think* the formula for **Rondos A & B** is

```
H = ((P*L*(P*L-1))/2) - P*((L*(L-1))/2)
```

*Where*

- H = number of passing lines ("handshakes")
- P = number of players
- L = number of discrete lateral positions per player

Since players cannot pass to themselves, those "handshakes" must be removed.

**With that, I have 2 questions:**

1. Is this the right formula for solving the number of passing lines ("handshakes") between players in a rondo
2. What is the formula for solving **Rondo C**?

Thank you in advance for your help!